# Alignment in exam class

Tags: exam

In the exam class, the alignment worked perfectly for the first question. After I insert a new page, for subsequent question, the alignment was not on the left and instead it was centered. I am not sure of what I should do futher to rectify the issue.

```
%Question 2%

\question \textbf{[10 marks]} \\  
The complex number $z$ has modulus $\sqrt{2}$ and argument $\frac{-\pi}{6}$, and the complex number $w$ has modulus $\sqrt{2}$ and argument $\frac{-\pi}{4}$.


\begin{parts}
```

[image]

Better code:

```
\documentclass{exam} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\begin{document} 
\pointsdroppedatright 
\bracketedpoints 
\begin{questions} 
\question The diagram below shows part of the graph of $y=e^{-2x} \cos x +2$. \fillwithdottedlines{\stretch{1}} 
\newpage 
\question The complex number $z$ has modulus $\sqrt{2}$ and argument $\frac{-\pi}{6}$
\end{questions} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet compilable, then we have not to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: For the first question, the alignment turned out well. Whereas for the second question, instead of left aligned, it turned out centre aligned.

Please kindly advise and apologies if my way of asking questions is not up to your expectations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to recreate your MWE, which works fine for me.

```
\documentclass{exam} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\begin{document} 
\pointsdroppedatright 
\bracketedpoints 
\begin{questions} 
\question The diagram below shows part of the graph of $y=e^{-2x} \cos x +2$. 
\fillwithdottedlines{\stretch{1}} 
\newpage 
\question The complex number $z$ has modulus $\sqrt{2}$ and argument $\frac{-\pi}{6}$.
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks John for your help. I realised where my error was. I added a picture in Question 1 and add the command \centering. I did this to place the picture in the middle. When I removed this command, the indentation for the second question was back to normal. Please advise further steps. Appreciate it lots.

\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{pic1.jpg} \centering